# Verificar se o aluno está simultaneamente em 2 disciplinas

Tags: sql, oracle

Preciso verificar se os alunos que estão matriculados simultaneamente nas 2 disciplinas
ex: Se o aluno estiver na disciplina 302 e 289 exibi-lo

Tentei fazer a seguinte query, porém não deu certo.

```
select mat_alu, cod_disc
from historicos
where cod_disc = 302 and cod_disc = 289 and ano = 2007 and semestre = 1;
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Uma solução ,.. Select mat_alu from historicos where cod_disc  in (302,289) and ... group by mat_alu having count(distinct cod_disc) = 2

Answer (score 2):

Sua query não funciona porque condição é inválida: `where cod_disc = 302 and cod_disc = 289`
Nunca haverá um registro onde um campo pode ser, **ao mesmo tempo**, igual a duas coisas distintas, ou será 302 ou 289.

O que precisa fazer é "existe, para um mesmo aluno, dois registros diferentes, onde as disciplinas sejam 302 e 289"?

Para isso, podemos fazer um `COUNT` para contar o número de ocorrências, e se for 2, é por existem os tais dois registros, por exemplo:

```
SELECT mat_alu,
       COUNT(*) TOTAL
  FROM historicos
 WHERE (cod_disc = 302 
    OR cod_disc = 289) 
   AND ano = 2007 
   AND semestre = 1
 GROUP BY mat_alu;
```

Com isso, quando o `TOTAL` for 2, o aluno está matricula em duas disciplinas (note que mudei o operador para OR, ou seja, o valor pode ser 302 **OU** 289).

Podemos melhorar mais, para trazer só os anulos nessas condições. Para isso usamos o `HAVING` para filtrar só os registros onde o "TOTAL" seja igual a 2:

```
SELECT mat_alu,
       COUNT(*) TOTAL
  FROM historicos
 WHERE (cod_disc = 302 
    OR cod_disc = 289) 
   AND ano = 2007 
   AND semestre = 1
 GROUP BY mat_alu
HAVING TOTAL = 2;
```

Pode ver um exemplo funcionando aqui: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c2XMvGQvvwJLfT39uSD1aU/0)